# Give unique ID in a while loop item

Tags: php, while-loop

How can I give a uniuqe ID for a item in a while loop.

Example:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 echo "$row['items']; <a href=\"GoToPageToEditThisItem\">Edit</a>";
}
```

Output:http://prntscr.com/2bto7g

So I can edit the appropriate item.

Comment: Does your table contain a unique/primary/auto_increment index? see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an ID (auto incremented/unique) in your table,

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 echo $row['items'] . '<a href="editItem.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a>';
}
```

You could then access the item using `$_GET["id"]`.

Comment: "Assuming you have a unique ID in your table" - and assuming that you don't have to take care of the proper encoding/escaping when printed as parameter in an href="..." attribute. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 $id = $row['id'];
 echo $row['items'].'<a href=\"GoToPageToEditThisItem\id\$id">Edit</a>';
}
```

Comment: Ok but the items are stored in the database item1 could be stored in the database as item 99.

Comment: Ahh I was thinking way to difficult I already know $itemId so simply id=$ItemId was enough... Thank you guys!